# Facebook like count on details and home page

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have a website that displays houses to the visitors. When the user wants to view a house, he/she clicks to view the house and a details page will show. With the url being `www.myhouses/details/123` (123 being the unique id for the house).

I added a Facebook like button to the details screen (`www.myhouses/details/123`) . Will this "like" be counting towards like for www.myhouses (the entire website) or only for the specific url.

Is there a way to get the count for all Facebook likes to my page, in the above mentioned scenario ?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That depends if you have defined the data-href attribute in the fb-like div.

To know all likes you have on your website. From what I know ( correct me if is wrong ). You need to map all your site urls and request using the Facebook Graph or using FQL to get the like of every single page, and so, sum then all.

Comment: So there is no way to like a certain "house" and then get the count on the house and on the website ?

Comment: No, no way for this.

You can use this link to test the Facebook Graph

https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/?method=GET&path=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com.br

Vote up if it help you.

Answer (score 1):

It depends. When you create a like button you pass the URL you are going to LIKE.

The documentation shows:

```
<iframe src="https://www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?href=YOUR_URL"
        scrolling="no" frameborder="0"
        style="border:none; width:450px; height:80px"></iframe>
```

If you put:

```
<iframe src="https://www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?href=www.myhouses.com"
        scrolling="no" frameborder="0"
        style="border:none; width:450px; height:80px"></iframe>
```

you are going to like your site, if:

```
<iframe src="https://www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?href=www.myhouses.com/details/123"
        scrolling="no" frameborder="0"
        style="border:none; width:450px; height:80px"></iframe>
```

you are going to like your house link.

Comment: I want to use the last one mentioned, to like my house link, but then i want to do the count on the house and on the website as a whole.

Comment: It doesn't seem to be possible to like 2 different objects (pages) at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you haven't defined it with the `data-href` attribute, it will use the current URL, otherwise it will use the defined url.

```
<div class="fb-like" data-href="http://www.yourdomain.com" data-send="false" data-width="450" data-show-faces="false"></div>
```